# Why is this low pass considered reckless and resulted in a license loss?

Tags: regulations, pilot-certification, aerobatics, private-jets

The first clip in the following video shows a Falcon 900X performing a low pass:

What exactly is considered reckless here and why would the pilot lose his license?

Comment: Oh yeah, that'll do it.  If he'd stayed on the runway axis, he probably would've been alright.

Comment: How do you know the pilot lost their license?

Comment: I thought that picture couldn't be a real frame from the video as the plane looks like its wing tip is barely 10 feet off the ground, but nope, it's real..

Comment: Pretty sure people only get to fly jets at treetop height when those jets have guns on them, or are at least trainers for the ones that do.

Comment: *Don't sink.* - At that speed, another few degrees of roll and it goes in the ground. [B 52 JET AIRCRAFT CRASH At Fairchild Air Force base.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-S_NM--evM)

Comment: @copper.hat I'm going out on a limb here, but I'm guessing OP simply read the title of the video and took that as fact.  Certainly the pilot should **expect** to lose their licence after a stunt like that.

Comment: @J... Without knowing the circumstances it is impossible to judge whether or not it was reckless. ATC may have requested it for some reason.

Comment: @copper.hat ATC does not request such things, to the best of my knowledge, under ANY circumstances.  The only excuse for the pilot here would be if the aircraft was damaged and uncontrollable.

Comment: @J... Sure they do. You do not know the circumstances. I have been requested to do odd things from time to time. Such as a low level tight orbit on finals into Dublin airport. Or to abort a landing and make an immediate turn.

Comment: @copper.hat A turn before runway end and *well* below 400agl?  To skim right over airport buildings and other parked aircraft?!  That's just wanton recklessness.  I would be shocked if ATC requested that the pilot flew that manoeuvre.  There would have to be some pretty irregular circumstances out of sight of the camera, I would think.  But yes, I'll grant the vanishingly small probability that something else might be going on, I suppose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This event appears to have taken place in Argentina.  However, I cannot determine if it is a civil aircraft of U.S. registry ("N" numbered aircraft).

If it is not a civil aircraft of U.S. registry and took place in Argentina then the applicable U.S. regulations (14 CFR Part 91) would *not* apply.

However, if the aircraft was a civil aircraft of U.S. registry operating in Argentina then, according to [14 CFR 91.703 (a) (3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.703) most of 14 CFR Part 91 would apply, *"...so far as it is not inconsistent with applicable regulations of the foreign country where the aircraft is operated or Annex 2 of the Convention on International Civil Aviation."*

---

If 14 CFR Part 91 does apply, the regulations and policy shown below would likely be applied regarding the pilot(s), assuming the FAA was made aware of the issue.

[14 CFR 91.119 (c) - Minimum safe altitudes](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.119) requires that an aircraft remain at least 500 feet AGL (or no closer than 500 feet to any person, vessel, vehicle, or structure in sparsely populated areas).

Also, as noted in [FAA Order 2150.3C - FAA Compliance and Enforcement Program](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FAA_Order_2150.3C_CHG_7.pdf) on page 9-3 (near the bottom of the page) "Reckless" is defined as:

> *Reckless*. A violation is reckless when the violator's conduct demonstrates a gross disregard for or deliberate indifference to safety or or a safety standard.

[14 CFR 91.13 (a) Careless or reckless operation](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.13) states:

> (a) Aircraft operations for the purpose of air navigation. No person may operate an aircraft in a careless or reckless manner so as to endanger the life or property of another.

Also, on page 9-22 of the FAA Order 2150.3C (see the image below) note that even over an uncongested area low flying is considered as a "Severity 2" violation (with Severity 3 being the most severe).

[image]

So, if the pilot's license was revoked it probably was due to the regulations and
policies noted above.

(During airshows where aircraft are flying/operating lower than FAR 91.119 - Minimum Safe Altitudes would allow, an FAA Waiver is written that contains provisions and restrictions that provide for an equivalent level of safety)

Comment: Did FAA regulations apply to this flight? The caption mentions Argentina, and I couldn’t make out a registration from the video. There’s no doubt it’s reckless, though!

Comment: @Pondlife: if it was an civil aircraft of U.S. registry far part 91 (most of it) would apply. I did not see in the video if it was an "N" numbered airplane, but I see now that it probably occurred in Argentina. I will make some adjustment to my answer. See FAR 91.703. Good catch!

Comment: Argentina seems to have quite strict laws on this as well: "ARTICLE 221. – Shall be punished with imprisonment from 6 months to 4 years: [...] 2) The one who, without authorization, made risky flights endangering the life or property of third parties;" ([Aeronautical Code of Argentina](http://servicios.infoleg.gob.ar/infolegInternet/anexos/20000-24999/24963/texact.htm), translated by Google).

Comment: Are these minimum altitude limits applicable when the aircraft is cleared for low pass over the runway? (or announces a low pass over an uncontrolled airport runway)

Comment: @VladimirF: yes, even if cleared for a low pass the minimum regulatory altitudes apply in accordance with FAR 91.119. This is why (in the U.S.) the FAA issues a written "Waiver" for airshow pilots that contain provisions and restrictions (e.g. how close the crowd can be to the runway, etc.) in order to authorize low flying during the show.

Comment: @757toga Thank you. I found a question about that, but the answer doesn't have many votes and the comments were inconclusive https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/54033/whats-the-minimum-legal-height-in-europe-for-a-low-pass-at-an-airport

Comment: @VladimirF: ATC cannot authorize a deviation from FAR 91.119. If cleared by ATC for a low approach the pilot is expected to descend to the approach end of the runway and then start a climb to an appropriate altitude.

Comment: Are there exceptions for cases where this might be considered legal? For example performing this low pass over ones own property?

Comment: If the rules of another country are more lax than US rules, in what cases would pilots be expected to still abide by US rules, and in what cases would the more relaxed rules apply?

Comment: @supercat: I don't have any better interpretation than what FAR 91.703 states. See the link to that regulation in my answer above.

Comment: @user19440: FAR 91.119 (minimum safe altitudes) does not make any distinction as to whether or not low flying is over you own property. I am not aware of any exceptions.

Comment: 40 (aerobatic flight) and 41 (collision hazard) too, no? And 43 (deviation from ATC clearance); no, you are *not* cleared to buzz the tower.

Comment: When you are landing or taking off 91.119 does not apply.

Comment: @copper.hat: you're correct, as long as you actually land or are taking off from the runway/surface. The limitations/restrictions of 91.119 apply if you are making a low pass that is not specifically necessary for takeoff or landing. Low altitude flight above the runway (or anywhere else) is subject to the limits of 91.119. Also (at least in the U.S.) ATC does not have the authority to authorize a deviation from 91.119.